# Writing a function that repeats a string n times and separates each repetition with another string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, repeat

I'm trying to write a function that needs 3 inputs: a string (named `word`), an integer (named `n`), another string (named `delim'`,
then the function must repeats the string named `word` `n` times (and that's easy) and between each repetition it has to insert the string named `delim`.

I know that this code works:

```
print('me', 'cat', 'table', sep='&')
```

but this code doesn't:

```
print(cat*3, sep='&')
```

The code I wrote is pretty much useless but I'll post it anyway — there could be other errors or inaccuracies that I'm not aware of.

```
def repeat(word, n, delim):
    print(word*n , sep=delim)

def main():
    string=input('insert a string:  ')
    n=int(input('insert number of repetition:  '))
    delim=input('insert the separator:  ')

    repeat(string, n, delim)

main()
```

For example, given this input:

```
word='cat', n=3, delim='petting'
```

I would like the program to give back:

```
catpettingcatpettingcat
```

Comment: "but this code doesn't:" The trick is that each `'cat'` has to be a **separate argument** to `print`. That's what the unpacking `*` operator is useful for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [iterable unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments) and only use the `print` function:

```
def repeat(word, n, delim):
    print(*n*[word], sep=delim)
```

Or just use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
def repeat(word, n, delim):
    print(delim.join(word for _ in range(n)))
```

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for `print('petting'.join(["cat"]*3))`

```
$ python3
Python 3.6.9 (default, Jan 26 2021, 15:33:00) 
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print('petting'.join(["cat"]*3))
catpettingcatpettingcat
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Function returning a string object

```
def repeat(word, n, sep='&'):
    return sep.join(word for _ in range(n))

print(repeat('Hallo', 3))
```

Output

```
hallo&hallo&hallo
```

Answer (score 0):

To repeat the word you can use a loop and a variable to store the output of your repeat method. Here is an example of how you could implement it.

```
def repeat(word, n, delim):
    str = ''
    for i in range(n): # this will repeat the next line n times.
        str += word + delim 
    return str[0:len(str) - len(delim)] # len(delim) will remove the last 'delim' from 'str'.
```

In your main method, you will need to print what is returned from the repeat method. For example:

```
print(repeat(string, n, delim))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out

```
def myprint(word, n, delim):
    ans = [word] * n 
    return delim.join(ans)
    
print(myprint('cat',3,'petting'))
```

```
catpettingcatpettingcat
```